# How can I lock other's app on iOS

Tags: ios

I know it is not possible to lock other's app from my app using standard SDK API's(If I am wrong please let me know).

Is it possible to lock/password protect other's app from my app **using SDK private API's but without jailbreaking iPhone?**

Please don't answer just bluntly saying "Apple does not allow this". I know there would be no official way of doing it, and certainly not for an App Store application, and I know there are some apps like AppLocker which lock other's app.

Comment: Which app can lock other apps on the App Store?

Comment: @Mannopson Like AppLocker http://www.idownloadblog.com/2017/06/10/applocker-ios-10/ but this app is only for jailbroken iphone

Comment: No maybe! Because it's an App Store and you can't create an app like that. It's a sandbox issue.

Comment: I can't imagine how you would do this even on a desktop OS without root permissions, so, no, this is almost certainly not possible without jailbreaking.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to lock/password protect other's app from my app using SDK private API's but without jailbreaking iPhone?

No. Your app is sandboxed; even with private APIs, you can't subvert the file system to see outside your app's container. Thus, you can't see any other apps, and you can't see the regions of the disk that would allow you to do this sort of thing.

Being able to see those regions is *exactly* what jailbreaking is. Thus, you would *have* to jailbreak in order to accomplish this.